# Propel erros on site migration

Tags: php, build, migration, propel, rebuild

My website directory was moved to another server but the database is still the same. Will this cause an issue on Propel? Because I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'propel/Propel.php'
>   (include_path='/www/inc:/var/www/www.samplesite.com/classes:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
>   in /var/www/www.samplesite.com/config.php on line 7

Or is this error caused by something else, not Propel?

Do I perhaps need to execute a rebuild of the Propel installation in order to correct the paths by itself?

Comment: Not related to Propel at all. It seems that it can't find propel's files. There are plenties of questions about that error. You should try to [search on SO first](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Fatal+error%3A+require_once%28%29%3A+Failed+opening+required).

Comment: I see. So once you migrate from one server to another, you don't really have to do anything to Propel? @j0k

Comment: @j0k Tried changing paths but there's just a lot mostly related to Propel paths.. I'm thinking there's something that needs to be done to re-build Propel and correct the paths itself

Comment: Is Propel embedded with your project or you're using a dependency mechanism at the server level ? Try o find the PHP include_path property of the previous server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `set_include_path()` just before you call `require_once`